# Laravel : page not found when passing two parameters on api

Tags: laravel, routes, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass two value as parameters in Laravel to API route :

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->group(function () {
    //Updat Order Status
Route::get('/update_order/{user_id}/{order_id}', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'update_order']);
});
```

the Controller is :

```
public function update_order($user_id , $order_id)
    {
        $user = User::select('role')->where('id',$user_id)->first();
        $role = $user[0]->role;
        dd($role);
    }
```

I will create middleware later for admin AUTH, when I try to test the route in postman I get :

> 404 NOT FOUND

I used this URL on post man : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/update_order?user_id=1&order_id=1`
Where is my mistake ?

Comment: You need to test with url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/update_order/1/1` route parameters are not same as query parameters. Route parameters are a part of the url without query string

Comment: @Donkarnash  Thank you ,must I use same in mobile app request?

Comment: Yes pls understand your route is defined with url as `/update_order/{user_id}/{order_id}` so you need to substitute the values for route parameters `user_id` and `order_id` with actual values which may come dynamically from frontend. If you don't substitute the values then url would be incomplete and you will get 404 NOT FOUND error

Comment: You might want to read up on [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters).